# How to make sense of this result?

Tags: python, tuples

I am new to Python. Here is a question I have about lists:
It is said that lists are mutable and tuples are immutable. But when I write the following:

```
L1 = [1, 2, 3]
L2 = (L1, L1)
L1[1] = 5
print L2
```

the result is

```
([1, 5, 3], [1, 5, 3])
```

instead of

```
([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
```

But `L2` is a tuple and tuples are immutable. Why is it that when I change the value of `L1`, the value of `L2` is also changed?

Comment: Seems like you create a view and not a deep copy?

Answer (score 7):

From the Python documentation (http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html), note:

> The value of an immutable container object that contains a reference to a mutable 
>   object can change when the latter’s value is changed; however the container is 
>   still considered immutable, because the collection of objects it contains cannot 
>   be changed. So, immutability is not strictly the same as having an unchangeable 
>   value, it is more subtle.

Answer (score 4):

The tuple is immutable, but the list inside the tuple is mutable.  You changed L1 (the list), not the tuple.  The tuple contains two copies of L1, so they both show the change, since they are actually the same list.

If an object is "immutable", that doesn't automatically mean everything it touches is also immutable.  You can put mutable objects inside immutable objects, and that won't stop you from continuing to mutate the mutable objects.

Answer (score 4):

The tuple didn't get modified, it still contains the same duplicate references to list you gave it.

You modified a *list* (`L1`), *not* the tuple (or more precisely, not the *reference* to the list in the tuple).

For instance you would *not* have been able to do

```
  L2[1] = 5
```

because tuples *are* immutable as you correctly state.

So the tuple wasn't changed, but the list that the tuple contained a reference to was modified (since both entries were references to the same list, both values in the output changed to `5`). No value in the tuple was changed.

It may help if you think of reference as a "pointer" in this context.

**EDIT** (based on question by OP in comments below):

About references, lists and copies, maybe these examples will be helpful:

```
L=range(5)
s = (L, L[:]) # a reference to the original list and a copy

s
([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

then changing L[2]

```
L[2] = 'a'
```

gives:

```
s
([0, 1, 'a', 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])  # copy is not changed
```

Notice that the "2nd" list didn't change, since it contains a copy.

Now,

```
L=range(5)
```

we are creating two copies of the list and giving the references to the tuple

```
s = (L[:], L[:])

now 
L[2] = 'a'
```

doesn't affect anything but the original list L

```
s
 ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. When I mention a list in defining a variable, is there any general rule telling me when the list is merely contained as a reference, and when the list is contained as a copy? For example if I define the variable A as L1[1], L1 is contained as a copy, but as you said, when I define L2 as [L1, L1], L1 is contained as a reference.

Comment: @user1641021  If you use the slice notation (e.g., L1[:]), you are making a copy of the list. I'll ad a bit more on this to my answer, perhaps it will be helpful.

Comment: @user1641021 I updated my answer to address some of your questions, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that tuples are immutable: L2 is an immutable tuple of two references to L1 (not, as it might first appear, a tuple of two lists), and L1 is not immutable. When you alter L1, you aren't altering L2, just the objects that L2 references.

Answer (score 2):

Use **deepcopy** instead of `=` :

> > from copy import deepcopy
> >     L2 = deepcopy(L1)

Answer (score 1):

The tuple contains two references, each to the same list (not copies of the list, as you might have expected). Hence, changes in the list will still show up in the tuple (since the tuple contains only the references), but the tuple itself is not altered. Therefore, it's immutability is not violated.

Comment: If I write L1 = [1, 2, 3]
    A = L1[1]
    L1[1] = 5
    Print A

Comment: @user1641021: in that snippet, first you make a list and name it L1.  Then you bind the name A to the object referred to by L1[1], which is the integer 2.  Then you change the second element of L1 to be 5.  Then you print A, which is still 2; you "pointed" A at the integer 2, not at "the second element of L1".

Comment: But if I write L1 = [1, 2, 3]
               A = L1[1]
               L1[1] = 5
               Print A       The result will be 2 instead of 5. Is that because 'L1[1]'contains a copy of L1, not a reference of L1, so that even L1 changed its value, L1[1] wouldn't?

Comment: thanks. sorry I just realized you answered my question. I thought my first response didn't come through.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples being immutable means only one thing -- once you construct a tuple, it's impossible to modify it. Lists, on the other hand, can be added elements to, removed elements from. But, both tuples and lists are concerned with the elements they contain, but not with what those elements are.

In Python, and this has nothing to do with tuples or lists, when you add a simple value, like an int, it gets represented as is, but any complex value like a list, a tuple, or any other class-type object  is **always** stored as reference.

If you were to convert your tuple to a `set()`, you'd get an error message that might surprise you, but given the above it should make sense:

```
>>> L=range(5)
>>> s = (L, L[:]) # a reference to the original list and a copy
>>> set(1, 2, s)
>>> set((1, 2, s))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

As values of a `set` must never change once they are added to the set, any mutable value contained inside the immutable tuple `s` raises `TypeError`.

Comment: This makes it seem like `int`s aren't "stored by reference" in the same way that "complex value"s are, and are instead "represented as is".   But an `int` is an object in exactly the same way a `tuple` is.